# How to correctly test query params, if request contains only string types?

Tags: python, exception

I have the following methods:

```
def validate_find_videos(request):
   radius = request.query['radius']
   if not isinstance(radius, int) and not isinstance(radius, float):
      raise WrongRequestData(
        "Please, specify the correct type of radius value. "
        "It must be a numeric value")

   address = request.query['address']
   if (not isinstance(address, str)):
       raise WrongRequestData(
        "Please, specify the correct type of address value. "
        "It must be a string")
```

How to correctly test `curl request` params if it always returns `string`, so `radius` will be a `string` and I always will throw `WrongRequestData`

Comment: See if you can convert it to a number and catch any error using `try`/`except`

Comment: Which framework are you using? That is, what is this `request` object and where does it come from? Also, if you just need to know if `radius` is a number you can do `isinstance(radius, numbers.Number)` (after importing `numbers.Number`, that is).